# Is hardware encoding of VP8/VP9 on Android with error resilience possible?

Tags: video, encoding, android-mediacodec, packet-loss, vp9

I try to use the MediaCodec class to encode to VP8/VP9.
Basically this works but transmitting the generated data using UDP results in many artifacts when decoding. This is because there is some packet loss.

I know vpxenc has an option to enable error resilience. Is there an option for this in MediaCodec? My hope is to reduce the artifacts.
I have found the option KEY_INTRA_REFRESH_PERIOD but it seems not to be supported with VP8/VP9 on the device i tried.

My setup is:
Sony Xperia XZ Premium (Qualcomm MSM8998 Snapdragon 835, Adreno 540).
I use MediaCodec to encode VP8/VP9 and transfer the data as UDP packets to a PC running ffplay (ffplay udp://0.0.0.0:6000) or vlc. 
I put the data in ivf packets before sending.

I would also like to know if trying to use MediaCodec for encoding is a good idea at all. The app i would like to make is something like a Video Call app.
My first impression of the encoding quality MediaCodec does output is not good. When encoding with 500kBit and 640x480 the result is not quite good. Especially when the cam is moved, the quality drops considerably (same for h264). Should I better use the vpx library directly?

Comment: In general, hardware encoding via MediaCodec is definitely to prefer over software encoding. For this particular case, I don't know whether there's any standard way of controlling this behaviour for VP8/VP9 encoders via MediaCodec/OMX, and if any/all of the encoders actually implement or support that control, if it exists. Using H264, if it's an option for you, would probably be more reliable in this aspect.